# How to get text from EditText into integer variable

Tags: java, android

i try to get the the value of the text from the EditText as an integer number , but i found that every time i insert any value it calculate the initialized value from the catch , so what's the solved for this problem

the result become =0

```
    public Button bu,bu2,bu3,bu4,bu5;
int num=0,num2=0,num3=0,result=0;
public EditText on,on2,on3,on4;
public TextView tex  ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monthlycalc);

    bu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.year);
    bu.setOnClickListener(this);

    bu2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
    bu2.setOnClickListener(this);

    bu3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    bu3.setOnClickListener(this);

    bu4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.H1);
    bu4.setOnClickListener(this);

    bu5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ron);
    bu5.setOnClickListener(this);


    try {
        on=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loanAm);
        num=Integer.valueOf(on.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num=0;
    }

    try {
        on2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.intRate);
        num2=Integer.valueOf(on2.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num2=0;
    }

    try {
        on3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lonTerm);
        num=Integer.valueOf(on3.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num3=0;
    }
    tex  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monPay);
    result=num+num2+num3;
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId()==R.id.calc)
        tex.setText(String.valueOf(result));    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code to `onClick`
You are trying to get the values inside `onCreate` which happens while the activity is being launched and all `EditText`s are empty, put it inside the `onClick` and it will work :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monthlycalc);
    bu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.year);
    bu.setOnClickListener(this);
    bu2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
    bu2.setOnClickListener(this);
    bu3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    bu3.setOnClickListener(this);
    bu4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.H1);
    bu4.setOnClickListener(this);
    bu5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ron);
    on=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loanAm);
    on2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.intRate);
    on3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lonTerm);
    tex  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monPay);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    try {
        num=Integer.valueOf(on.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num=0;
    }

    try {
        num2=Integer.valueOf(on2.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num2=0;
    }

    try {
        num=Integer.valueOf(on3.getText().toString().trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        num3=0;
    }
    result=num+num2+num3;
    if (v.getId()==R.id.calc)
        tex.setText(String.valueOf(result));    
}
```

Comment: i've done it but in this case the first number didn't add to the sumation @Shereef Marzouk

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain more ?

Comment: in this case the result become num2+num3 only , however i didn't change anything just move it to the onClick method

Answer (score 0):

Because you have maybe Chars or Whitespaces in your String which are not numeric.

Parse it using regex.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+"); // the regex
final ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // results
while (matcher.find()) { // for each match
   ints.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group())); // convert to int 
}
```

If you really want to remove all whitespaces dont use trim. Use

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

which removes all tabs aswell

And make sure that your values are grabbed when you click the button, not before, since it dont have any values inside while initializing, if you dont define a defaultValue.